# Bitcoind doesn't start

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, nodes

Im trying to make [Stadicus](https://github.com/Stadicus/guides/blob/master/raspibolt/) guide work for both Bitcoin Core & LND

I did download the blockchain and moved to the HDD on my Rasp3

However, when starting the bitcoind service, im having this debug.log

---

```
2019-02-23T23:47:58Z Bitcoin Core version v0.17.1 (release build)
2019-02-23T23:47:58Z InitParameterInteraction: parameter interaction: -whitelistforcerelay=1 -> setting -whitelistrelay=1
2019-02-23T23:47:58Z Assuming ancestors of block 0000000000000000002e63058c023a9a1de233554f28c7b21380b6c9003f36a8 have valid signatures.
2019-02-23T23:47:58Z Setting nMinimumChainWork=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000028822fef1c230963535a90d
2019-02-23T23:47:58Z Using the 'standard' SHA256 implementation
2019-02-23T23:47:58Z Default data directory /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin
2019-02-23T23:47:58Z Using data directory /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin
2019-02-23T23:47:58Z Using config file /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf
2019-02-23T23:47:58Z Using at most 40 automatic connections (1024 file descriptors available)
2019-02-23T23:47:58Z Using 16 MiB out of 32/2 requested for signature cache, able to store 524288 elements
2019-02-23T23:47:58Z Using 16 MiB out of 32/2 requested for script execution cache, able to store 524288 elements
2019-02-23T23:47:58Z Using 4 threads for script verification
2019-02-23T23:47:58Z scheduler thread start
2019-02-23T23:47:58Z HTTP: creating work queue of depth 16
2019-02-23T23:47:58Z Config options rpcuser and rpcpassword will soon be deprecated. Locally-run instances may remove rpcuser to use cookie-based auth, or may be replaced with rpcauth. Please see share/rpcauth for rpcauth auth generation.
2019-02-23T23:47:58Z HTTP: starting 4 worker threads
2019-02-23T23:47:58Z Using wallet directory /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin
2019-02-23T23:47:58Z init message: Verifying wallet(s)...
2019-02-23T23:47:58Z Using BerkeleyDB version Berkeley DB 4.8.30: (April  9, 2010)
2019-02-23T23:47:58Z Using wallet wallet.dat
2019-02-23T23:47:58Z BerkeleyEnvironment::Open: LogDir=/home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/database ErrorFile=/home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/db.log
2019-02-23T23:47:58Z Cache configuration:
2019-02-23T23:47:58Z * Using 2.0MiB for block index database
2019-02-23T23:47:58Z * Using 8.0MiB for chain state database
2019-02-23T23:47:58Z * Using 90.0MiB for in-memory UTXO set (plus up to 47.7MiB of unused mempool space)
2019-02-23T23:47:58Z init message: Loading block index...
2019-02-23T23:47:58Z Opening LevelDB in /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/blocks/index
2019-02-23T23:47:58Z Opened LevelDB successfully
2019-02-23T23:47:58Z Using obfuscation key for /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/blocks/index: 0000000000000000
```

Same log goes on and on every minute.

Tried with bitcoind -reindex, however, all the reindex blocks goes to my /root/.bitcoin/blocks folder and gets filled in 2 hours (12gb of reindex)
I also don't understand why the -reindex option goes towards to my /root/ folder instead of /mnt/hdd when i try to run bitcoind normally.

Anyone has any clue about this? Thanks you!

An even bigger loop log file

```
2019-02-24T14:19:56Z Bitcoin Core version v0.17.1 (release build)
2019-02-24T14:19:56Z InitParameterInteraction: parameter interaction: -whitelistforcerelay=1 -> setting -whitelistrelay=1
2019-02-24T14:19:56Z Assuming ancestors of block 0000000000000000002e63058c023a9a1de233554f28c7b21380b6c9003f36a8 have valid signatures.
2019-02-24T14:19:56Z Setting nMinimumChainWork=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000028822fef1c230963535a90d
2019-02-24T14:19:56Z Using the 'standard' SHA256 implementation
2019-02-24T14:19:56Z Default data directory /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin
2019-02-24T14:19:56Z Using data directory /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin
2019-02-24T14:19:56Z Using config file /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf
2019-02-24T14:19:56Z Using at most 40 automatic connections (1024 file descriptors available)
2019-02-24T14:19:56Z Using 16 MiB out of 32/2 requested for signature cache, able to store 524288 elements
2019-02-24T14:19:56Z Using 16 MiB out of 32/2 requested for script execution cache, able to store 524288 elements
2019-02-24T14:19:56Z Using 4 threads for script verification
2019-02-24T14:19:56Z scheduler thread start
2019-02-24T14:19:56Z HTTP: creating work queue of depth 16
2019-02-24T14:19:56Z Config options rpcuser and rpcpassword will soon be deprecated. Locally-run instances may remove rpcuser to use cookie-based auth, or may be replaced with rpcauth. Please see share/rpcauth for rpcauth auth generation.
2019-02-24T14:19:56Z HTTP: starting 4 worker threads
2019-02-24T14:19:56Z Using wallet directory /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin
2019-02-24T14:19:56Z init message: Verifying wallet(s)...
2019-02-24T14:19:56Z Using BerkeleyDB version Berkeley DB 4.8.30: (April  9, 2010)
2019-02-24T14:19:56Z Using wallet wallet.dat
2019-02-24T14:19:56Z BerkeleyEnvironment::Open: LogDir=/home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/database ErrorFile=/home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/db.log
2019-02-24T14:19:57Z Cache configuration:
2019-02-24T14:19:57Z * Using 2.0MiB for block index database
2019-02-24T14:19:57Z * Using 8.0MiB for chain state database
2019-02-24T14:19:57Z * Using 90.0MiB for in-memory UTXO set (plus up to 47.7MiB of unused mempool space)
2019-02-24T14:19:57Z init message: Loading block index...
2019-02-24T14:19:57Z Opening LevelDB in /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/blocks/index
2019-02-24T14:20:00Z Opened LevelDB successfully
2019-02-24T14:20:00Z Using obfuscation key for /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/blocks/index: 0000000000000000
2019-02-24T14:20:22Z LoadBlockIndexDB: last block file = 1409
2019-02-24T14:20:22Z LoadBlockIndexDB: last block file info: CBlockFileInfo(blocks=120, size=133788575, heights=547036...547155, time=2018-10-23...2018-10-24)
2019-02-24T14:20:22Z Checking all blk files are present...
2019-02-24T14:20:22Z Opening LevelDB in /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/chainstate
2019-02-24T14:20:26Z Opened LevelDB successfully
2019-02-24T14:20:26Z Using obfuscation key for /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/chainstate: 81292deb9b99a760
2019-02-24T14:21:26Z 




2019-02-24T14:21:26Z Bitcoin Core version v0.17.1 (release build)
2019-02-24T14:21:26Z InitParameterInteraction: parameter interaction: -whitelistforcerelay=1 -> setting -whitelistrelay=1
2019-02-24T14:21:26Z Assuming ancestors of block 0000000000000000002e63058c023a9a1de233554f28c7b21380b6c9003f36a8 have valid signatures.
2019-02-24T14:21:26Z Setting nMinimumChainWork=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000028822fef1c230963535a90d
2019-02-24T14:21:26Z Using the 'standard' SHA256 implementation
2019-02-24T14:21:26Z Default data directory /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin
2019-02-24T14:21:26Z Using data directory /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin
2019-02-24T14:21:26Z Using config file /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf
2019-02-24T14:21:26Z Using at most 40 automatic connections (1024 file descriptors available)
2019-02-24T14:21:26Z Using 16 MiB out of 32/2 requested for signature cache, able to store 524288 elements
2019-02-24T14:21:26Z Using 16 MiB out of 32/2 requested for script execution cache, able to store 524288 elements
2019-02-24T14:21:26Z Using 4 threads for script verification
2019-02-24T14:21:26Z scheduler thread start
2019-02-24T14:21:26Z HTTP: creating work queue of depth 16
2019-02-24T14:21:26Z Config options rpcuser and rpcpassword will soon be deprecated. Locally-run instances may remove rpcuser to use cookie-based auth, or may be replaced with rpcauth. Please see share/rpcauth for rpcauth auth generation.
2019-02-24T14:21:26Z HTTP: starting 4 worker threads
2019-02-24T14:21:26Z Using wallet directory /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin
2019-02-24T14:21:26Z init message: Verifying wallet(s)...
2019-02-24T14:21:26Z Using BerkeleyDB version Berkeley DB 4.8.30: (April  9, 2010)
2019-02-24T14:21:26Z Using wallet wallet.dat
2019-02-24T14:21:26Z BerkeleyEnvironment::Open: LogDir=/home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/database ErrorFile=/home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/db.log
2019-02-24T14:21:28Z Cache configuration:
2019-02-24T14:21:28Z * Using 2.0MiB for block index database
2019-02-24T14:21:28Z * Using 8.0MiB for chain state database
2019-02-24T14:21:28Z * Using 90.0MiB for in-memory UTXO set (plus up to 47.7MiB of unused mempool space)
2019-02-24T14:21:28Z init message: Loading block index...
2019-02-24T14:21:28Z Opening LevelDB in /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/blocks/index
2019-02-24T14:21:30Z Opened LevelDB successfully
2019-02-24T14:21:30Z Using obfuscation key for /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/blocks/index: 0000000000000000
2019-02-24T14:21:52Z LoadBlockIndexDB: last block file = 1409
2019-02-24T14:21:52Z LoadBlockIndexDB: last block file info: CBlockFileInfo(blocks=120, size=133788575, heights=547036...547155, time=2018-10-23...2018-10-24)
2019-02-24T14:21:52Z Checking all blk files are present...
2019-02-24T14:21:53Z Opening LevelDB in /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/chainstate
2019-02-24T14:21:57Z Opened LevelDB successfully
2019-02-24T14:21:57Z Using obfuscation key for /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/chainstate: 81292deb9b99a760
2019-02-24T14:22:57Z 




2019-02-24T14:22:57Z Bitcoin Core version v0.17.1 (release build)
2019-02-24T14:22:57Z InitParameterInteraction: parameter interaction: -whitelistforcerelay=1 -> setting -whitelistrelay=1
2019-02-24T14:22:57Z Assuming ancestors of block 0000000000000000002e63058c023a9a1de233554f28c7b21380b6c9003f36a8 have valid signatures.
2019-02-24T14:22:57Z Setting nMinimumChainWork=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000028822fef1c230963535a90d
2019-02-24T14:22:57Z Using the 'standard' SHA256 implementation
2019-02-24T14:22:58Z Default data directory /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin
2019-02-24T14:22:58Z Using data directory /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin
2019-02-24T14:22:58Z Using config file /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf
2019-02-24T14:22:58Z Using at most 40 automatic connections (1024 file descriptors available)
2019-02-24T14:22:58Z Using 16 MiB out of 32/2 requested for signature cache, able to store 524288 elements
2019-02-24T14:22:58Z Using 16 MiB out of 32/2 requested for script execution cache, able to store 524288 elements
2019-02-24T14:22:58Z Using 4 threads for script verification
2019-02-24T14:22:58Z scheduler thread start
2019-02-24T14:22:58Z HTTP: creating work queue of depth 16
2019-02-24T14:22:58Z Config options rpcuser and rpcpassword will soon be deprecated. Locally-run instances may remove rpcuser to use cookie-based auth, or may be replaced with rpcauth. Please see share/rpcauth for rpcauth auth generation.
2019-02-24T14:22:58Z HTTP: starting 4 worker threads
2019-02-24T14:22:58Z Using wallet directory /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin
2019-02-24T14:22:58Z init message: Verifying wallet(s)...
2019-02-24T14:22:58Z Using BerkeleyDB version Berkeley DB 4.8.30: (April  9, 2010)
2019-02-24T14:22:58Z Using wallet wallet.dat
2019-02-24T14:22:58Z BerkeleyEnvironment::Open: LogDir=/home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/database ErrorFile=/home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/db.log
2019-02-24T14:22:58Z Cache configuration:
2019-02-24T14:22:58Z * Using 2.0MiB for block index database
2019-02-24T14:22:58Z * Using 8.0MiB for chain state database
2019-02-24T14:22:58Z * Using 90.0MiB for in-memory UTXO set (plus up to 47.7MiB of unused mempool space)
2019-02-24T14:22:58Z init message: Loading block index...
2019-02-24T14:22:58Z Opening LevelDB in /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/blocks/index
2019-02-24T14:23:02Z Opened LevelDB successfully
2019-02-24T14:23:02Z Using obfuscation key for /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/blocks/index: 0000000000000000
2019-02-24T14:23:23Z LoadBlockIndexDB: last block file = 1409
2019-02-24T14:23:23Z LoadBlockIndexDB: last block file info: CBlockFileInfo(blocks=120, size=133788575, heights=547036...547155, time=2018-10-23...2018-10-24)
2019-02-24T14:23:23Z Checking all blk files are present...
2019-02-24T14:23:24Z Opening LevelDB in /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/chainstate
2019-02-24T14:23:27Z Opened LevelDB successfully
2019-02-24T14:23:27Z Using obfuscation key for /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/chainstate: 81292deb9b99a760
2019-02-24T14:24:28Z 




2019-02-24T14:24:28Z Bitcoin Core version v0.17.1 (release build)
2019-02-24T14:24:28Z InitParameterInteraction: parameter interaction: -whitelistforcerelay=1 -> setting -whitelistrelay=1
2019-02-24T14:24:28Z Assuming ancestors of block 0000000000000000002e63058c023a9a1de233554f28c7b21380b6c9003f36a8 have valid signatures.
2019-02-24T14:24:28Z Setting nMinimumChainWork=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000028822fef1c230963535a90d
2019-02-24T14:24:28Z Using the 'standard' SHA256 implementation
2019-02-24T14:24:28Z Default data directory /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin
2019-02-24T14:24:28Z Using data directory /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin
2019-02-24T14:24:28Z Using config file /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf
2019-02-24T14:24:28Z Using at most 40 automatic connections (1024 file descriptors available)
2019-02-24T14:24:28Z Using 16 MiB out of 32/2 requested for signature cache, able to store 524288 elements
2019-02-24T14:24:28Z Using 16 MiB out of 32/2 requested for script execution cache, able to store 524288 elements
2019-02-24T14:24:28Z Using 4 threads for script verification
2019-02-24T14:24:28Z scheduler thread start
2019-02-24T14:24:28Z HTTP: creating work queue of depth 16
2019-02-24T14:24:28Z Config options rpcuser and rpcpassword will soon be deprecated. Locally-run instances may remove rpcuser to use cookie-based auth, or may be replaced with rpcauth. Please see share/rpcauth for rpcauth auth generation.
2019-02-24T14:24:28Z HTTP: starting 4 worker threads
2019-02-24T14:24:28Z Using wallet directory /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin
2019-02-24T14:24:28Z init message: Verifying wallet(s)...
2019-02-24T14:24:28Z Using BerkeleyDB version Berkeley DB 4.8.30: (April  9, 2010)
2019-02-24T14:24:28Z Using wallet wallet.dat
2019-02-24T14:24:28Z BerkeleyEnvironment::Open: LogDir=/home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/database ErrorFile=/home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/db.log
2019-02-24T14:24:29Z Cache configuration:
2019-02-24T14:24:29Z * Using 2.0MiB for block index database
2019-02-24T14:24:29Z * Using 8.0MiB for chain state database
2019-02-24T14:24:29Z * Using 90.0MiB for in-memory UTXO set (plus up to 47.7MiB of unused mempool space)
2019-02-24T14:24:29Z init message: Loading block index...
2019-02-24T14:24:29Z Opening LevelDB in /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/blocks/index
2019-02-24T14:24:33Z Opened LevelDB successfully
2019-02-24T14:24:33Z Using obfuscation key for /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/blocks/index: 0000000000000000
2019-02-24T14:24:55Z LoadBlockIndexDB: last block file = 1409
2019-02-24T14:24:55Z LoadBlockIndexDB: last block file info: CBlockFileInfo(blocks=120, size=133788575, heights=547036...547155, time=2018-10-23...2018-10-24)
2019-02-24T14:24:55Z Checking all blk files are present...
2019-02-24T14:24:56Z Opening LevelDB in /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/chainstate
```

Comment: This log excerpt doesn't show any errors.  Are you sure this is exactly where it loops?  What happens if you simply start bitcoind from the command line with no arguments?

Comment: @NateEldredge A simple bitcoind command just says Bitcoin server starting. This is the full loop (x4) I have edited the main message. Thanks you.

Comment: When you start with `-reindex`, how are you starting it? How are you starting it normally?

Comment: What's happening here is that the systemd file specifies that if bitcoind exits, it should be restarted. Your bitcoind is failing to start, dying, and then being restarted by systemd. This is why you see the repeated startup message in the debug.log file. To see what's causing it to crash, you need to start it without using systemctl and without the `-daemon` option. There should be an error printed in the console once it crashes.

Comment: @AndrewChow When i start it with 'bitcoind -reindex', when i want to start it normally, i do it with the command 'bitcoind'

Comment: @AndrewChow I have removed the systemd auto startup file, and now i need to start bitcoind manually. After removing the daemon=1 option from the bitcoin.conf this is the error i get. Using obfuscation key for /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/chainstate: 81292deb9b99a760
bitcoind: validation.cpp:2547: void CChainState::PruneBlockIndexCandidates(): Assertion `!setBlockIndexCandidates.empty()' failed. Doing a -reindex now seems to start on the correct HDD drive, so ill wait to see if the problem is solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your log does not show any errors. Nevertheless, you could have missed one step from the tutorial:

After creating the Folder for the Blockchain on your hard drive you could have forgotten to link the folder on your home folder to that on the hard drive.
This is made by:

`ln -s /mnt/hdd/bitcoin /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin`

Make sure you have this symlink.

Have you tried with testnet, if it stores the blockchain on your pi or on the hard drive?

Here is the linking part in the guide https://github.com/Stadicus/guides/blob/master/raspibolt/raspibolt_30_bitcoin.md#prepare-bitcoin-core-directory

Comment: Hey @dvg thanks for the reply. I actually went to check the symlink and appears to be ok https://gyazo.com/479b94df98c13c8d533903035db633ca.png When i did try the testnet, it actually went to the hard drive. This problem is driving me quite crazy as i don't know where the problem is actually.

Comment: As bad as it sounds if your problem persists try getting some steps back and do it another time. Often one simply overlooks something important.